# Facebook : How to publish/post to wall with custom 'verb'?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

**First, let's see what I want to make.**

Here is the screenshot of what I want. --> [image]

According to the screenshot, I'd like to make this kind of custom wall post which shows a custom verb like 'check-in', 'watched', 'listened to', etc.

Moreover, I'd like to customize the style of the content and message e.g. '30 others watched xxx on myApp'.

Another thing is making the app icon besides Like link at the bottom.

---

**Let's talk about my current skill.**

Currently, I've already taught myself about Graph API and Open Graph. I'm able create an app to post to wall and able to publish action by using opengraph.

But! Graph API and OpenGraph (I used) has never produced this kind of the post like the screenshot. I've already tried OpenGraph but it just keep publishing actions on activity feed *not on the wall*.

**My question is ...**
Can graph API or OpenGraph produce this kind of wall post?

If yes, how should I modified the request of the API?

If not, which API I have to learn to produce this kind of wall post?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook lets you add one custom action to a post. Here's an example:

```
$attachment = array
 (
 'access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken(),
 'message' => 'I\'ve been testing my IQ!',
 'name' => 'IC-YOUR-IQ',
 'caption' => 'This is my result:',
 'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/icyouriq/',
 'actions' => array('name'=>'Sweet FA','link'=>'http://www.facebookanswers.co.uk'),
 'description' => $cmsg,
 'picture' => 'http://www.facebookanswers.co.uk/img/misc/iq.jpg'
 );
```

The key field is the "actions" field. This expects an array consisting of two elements; "name" and "link".

You might be tempted to try adding more elements to that array, but it doesn't work. You can only have one custom action.

I blogged about it here, if you want to read up some more on it: http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=270

Comment: Thanks for response - I'll have a try. 

But one thing I found on fb dev page is they said that **Publish a new post on the given profile's feed/wall. Note that this feature will be removed soon.**

I just wonder what will replace this api? Open graph?

Comment: Ha! Welcome to the world of Facebook Development. Having a feature work one week then stop working is pretty much par for the course. Keep an eye on that Dev page.

Comment: I already tried what you suggested but the result is not as expected.
Please see screenshot here **http://i.imgur.com/VU7Zg.png**

I use PHP + Graph API to do this with the 'actions' param.

Comment: Please also see this screen. The result is still not as expected.
**http://imgur.com/I2WBY**

Comment: The reason you are getting NULL in that screenshot is because you have copied the code without supplying a description. If you look, I have used a variable $cmsg. If you replace that with a description you should have more luck. 

With regards to the icon, that is something assigned in the app properties. I mean in the pages where you specify url and get the app secret etc. Play around there.

Comment: Ah yes...I haven't noticed it. 
Thanks @Facebook Answer, I will try playing around.

Answer (score 1):

Just for other who view this question, you need to set explicit sharing to true

```
"fb:explicitly_shared=true"
```

Check out documentation at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing/)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/). What you call *verbs* are in fact [actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/actions/). The kinds of posts you want to make are **published actions**.

Here is a [How To Get Started With Open Graph](http://vimeo.com/29464909) video. You can also follow [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/). And here is [how to publish an action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publish-action/).

Last but not least, you'll find here [a plethora of technical guides](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/) to do nice things with Open Graph.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I've already followed the cook/recipe tutorial but the result I got is that it just publishes on my activity feed **not on my wall**. Am I missing something to make it publish to wall?

Comment: Can you use Open Graph to publish to wall?

Comment: See the result I got after calling open graph.
http://i.imgur.com/M82gt.png
**It just publishes to activity feed not on my wall.**
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to post to my wall

```
if (isset($_GET['publish'])){
        try {
            //$publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
            $publishStream = $facebook->api("/me/feed", 'post', array(
                'message' => "I love thinkdiff.net for facebook app development tutorials. :)", 
                'link'    => 'http://ithinkdiff.net',
                'picture' => 'http://thinkdiff.net/ithinkdiff.png',
                'name'    => 'iOS Apps & Games',
                'caption' => 'This is my result:',
                'actions' => array('name'=>'Sweet FA','link'=>'http://www.facebookanswers.co.uk'),
                'description'=> 'Checkout iOS apps and games from iThinkdiff.net. I found some of them are just awesome!'
                )
            );
            //as $_GET['publish'] is set so remove it by redirecting user to the base url 
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            d($e);
        }
        //$redirectUrl     = $fbconfig['baseurl'] . '/index.php?success=1';
        $redirectUrl     = $fbconfig['baseurl'] . '?success=1';
        header("Location: $redirectUrl");
    }
```